# How can I use hooks in a higher-order function that returns a ReactNative functional component in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks

Let me start with the working code that I'm trying to refactor. I'm trying to abstract button creation, and whatever I try, I keep getting the "hooks can only be called inside of the body of a functional component" error.

Following along with a tutorial, I've setup a navigation bar and a button that will take me from the home screen to a "Details" screen. Here's what works:

```
const DetailsButton = (): JSX.Element => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button title="Details" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')} />
  );
};

// And then later on...

<Stack.Screen name="Home" 
              component={HomeScreen} 
              options={{ title: 'Master', headerRight: DetailsButton }} />
```

That button will take me to the Details screen with no issue. But then I got to thinking that I could refactor this into a kind of button factory function:

```
interface BarButtonProps {
  title: string, 
  destination: string,
};

const BarButton = (buttonProps: BarButtonProps): () => JSX.Element => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (): JSX.Element => (
    <Button title={buttonProps.title} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(buttonProps.destination)} />
  );
}

const DetailsButton = BarButton({title: 'Details', destination: 'Details'});
```

My plan was to use the `DetailsButton` component as before. However, when I try to run the code, I get the hooks error. I thought I understood why, and so I tried the following variation:

```
const BarButton = (buttonProps: BarButtonProps): () => JSX.Element => {
  return (): JSX.Element => (
    <Button title={buttonProps.title} onPress={() => useNavigation().navigate(buttonProps.destination)} />
  );
}
```

In my mind, the hook now seemed to be within the functional component. But that only got me as far as the home screen. When I press the button I get the same hooks error again. I must be missing some subtle point.

Is it possible to create a higher-order function like this, one that uses a hook, or am I trying something impossible? If it's possible, can someone show me what would work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. Your factory should look like this:

```ts
const ButtonFactory = (props: ButtonProps): () => JSX.Element => {
  const { title, destination } = props;

  const MyButton = (): JSX.Element => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
      <Button title={title} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(destination)} />
    );
  }

  return MyButton;
};

export const DetailsButton = ButtonFactory({ title: 'Details', destination: 'Details' })
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to rename 'Button' in your code to something like 'MyButton' to get it to actually work. The app would still run, but the button at runtime would be dead. Pressing it resulted in nothing happening. My editor shows: "Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Intrinsic Attributes.'" I believe there is a conflict between the Button class and the "Button" variable. I'm going to make the edit to your code and mark it as the answer. Please let me know if my edit is wrong, and thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I transfered the code from the sandbox and forgot to change some names.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the current setup is that the `useNavigation` hook is being executed at the point where you call `BarButton({title: 'Details', destination: 'Details'})` rather than at the point where you call `<DetailsButton/>`.

When the `BarButton` function is called, you call `useNavigation` and then return a function component.  This is a violation of the rules of hooks.  You need to move the `useNavigation` hook so that it is called *inside* the created component.

Simply re-arrange the order of your lines:

```
const BarButton = (buttonProps: BarButtonProps): () => JSX.Element => {
    return (): JSX.Element => {
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        return (
            <Button title={buttonProps.title} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(buttonProps.destination)} />
        );
    }
}
```

---

Personally I would write the factory with a lowercase name to indicate that this is a function which *creates* a component rather than a component itself.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

interface BarButtonProps {
  title: string;
  destination: string;
}

const createBarButton = ({title, destination}: BarButtonProps) => (): JSX.Element => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <Button
      title={title}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate(destination)}
    />
  );
};

const DetailsButton = createBarButton({
  title: 'Details',
  destination: 'Details',
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed comments and compact code. You've helped me understand where I went wrong. (The other person answered first and solved my problem, so I marked his as the accepted answer for that reason.) What I see is my eyes got lost, and I was returning a function that wasn't actually returning anything. (I was missing a return statement, which I see when I compare my snippet to yours.) Thanks, again!

Comment: Your return was fine because the `=> (` syntax is an implicit/automatic return.  If it has brackets `=> {` then there is no automatic return, so you have to write `=> { return (`. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). I had to add an explicit `return` because I needed to add the brackets in order to include the hook call inside the returned component.